# Modify pandas dataframe within iterrows loop

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I'm new to Python.

I am trying to add prefix (Serial number) to an element within a data frame using for loop, to do with data cleaning/preparation before analysis.

The code is

```
a=pd.read_excel('C:/Users/HP/Desktop/WFH/PowerBI/CMM data.xlsx','CMM_unclean')
a['Serial Number'] = a['Serial Number'].apply(str)
print(a.iloc[72,1])

for index,row in a.iterrows():
    if len(row['Serial Number']) == 6:
        row['Serial Number'] = 'SR0' + row['Serial Number']
        print(row['Serial Number'])

print(a.iloc[72,1])
```

The output is

```
C:\Users\HP\anaconda3\envs\test\python.exe C:/Users/HP/PycharmProjects/test/first.py
101306
SR0101306
101306
```

I don't understand why this is happening inside the for loop, value is changing, however outside it is the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**This will never change the actual dataframe named `a`.**

TL;DR: The rows you get back from iterrows are copies that are no longer connected to the original data frame, so edits don't change your dataframe. However, you can use the index to access and edit the relevant row of the dataframe.

---

EXPLANATION

**Why?**

The rows you get back from `iterrows` are **copies** that are **no** **longer** **connected to the original data frame**, so edits don't change your dataframe. However, you can use the `index` to access and edit the relevant row of the dataframe.

---

The solution is this:

```
import pandas as pd

a = pd.read_excel("Book1.xlsx")
a['Serial Number'] = a['Serial Number'].apply(str)

a.head()
#    ID    Serial Number
# 0   1     SR0101306
# 1   2       1101306

print(a.iloc[0,1])
#101306

for index,row in a.iterrows():
    row = row.copy()
    if len(row['Serial Number']) == 6:
        # use the index and .loc method to alter the dataframe
        a.loc[index, 'Serial Number'] = 'SR0' + row['Serial Number']

print(a.iloc[0,1])
#SR0101306
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That's great explanation

Comment: glad that I could help. consider upvoting my answer if it helped

Answer (score 1):

[In the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html), I read (emphasis from there)

> You should **never modify** something you are iterating over. This is not guaranteed to work in all cases. Depending on the data types, the iterator returns a copy and not a view, and writing to it will have no effect.

Maybe this means in your case that a copy is made and no reference used. So the change applies temporarily to the copy but not to the data in the data frame.

Comment: Thanks Mr Wolf this was very useful

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already using `apply`, you could do this straight inside the function you call `apply` with:

```
def fix_serial(n):
    n_s = str(n)

    if len(n_s) == 6:
        n_s = 'SR' + n_s

    return n_s

a['Serial Number'] = a['Serial Number'].apply(fix_serial)
```